# Laravel Dusk merges in the default environment file

Tags: laravel, sqlite, testing, laravel-dusk

I just encountered the following scenario...

Imagine you use a MySQL database for your browser but would prefer a SQLite database for your testing with Dusk. I think that's quite a common case, or could be. So you might do something like this:

in your `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

in your `.env.dusk.local` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

One might think this would work, but the problem is that the environment files are merged when running Dusk. In other words, the Dusk configuration will become:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
```

And if you have a look at the default Laravel config for SQLite:

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

you will notice that it will try to get the `homestead` SQLite database in your project root, which does not exist - and obviously, your test will fail with errors like: `users table not found` for example, if you are running the default migrations.

Comment: I am missing the question here. What are you asking for?

Comment: @camilo Nothing - I just put this out here as reference for others trying to figure out why it might not work - I answered my own question straight away below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of solutions out there that overriding the configuration in the `CreatesApplication` trait of the test. Which can work, but you've got to remember that the same trait is being used by PHPUnit just as well. Also, it can lead to other tricky errors when setting up CI, like in my case. Furthermore, this does not *really* help with discoverability either...

They say elegance is in simplicity, so I think the best solution would be to change the default configuration and drop the environment variable from your sqlite connection. So this

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

would become this

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

If you still need to override this setup for any reason, you might introduce a *new* environment variable replacing `DB_DATABASE` that does not collide with the default set, but I think for most cases above is a perfect solution.